# ¿Cómo cambiar el formato de ingreso de fecha en Informix?

Tags: sql, date, informix

Mi base de datos recibe el formato `DD-MM-AAAA`, y necesito que sea a la inversa, `AAAA-MM-DD`.

¿Hay alguna manera de cambiar cómo recibe y se almacena la fecha en *Informix*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En español (Google)

Si. La forma principal es usar la variable de entorno [`DBDATE`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqlr.doc/ids_sqr_212.htm). Usted establecería:

```
export DBDATE = "Y4MD-"
```

Esto producirá cuatro dígitos para el año y dos para el mes y el día. La entrada también se guiará por ella, sin duda aceptará `2019-09-28`, pero también variaciones más flexibles como `2018-9-28` o `2019/9/28` (el pedido es más importante). A menos que haya configurado también la variable de entorno `DBCENTURY`, ingresar `19-9-28` también producirá el mismo resultado.

---

In English

Yes.  The primary way is using the [`DBDATE`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqlr.doc/ids_sqr_212.htm) environment variable.  You would set:

```
export DBDATE="Y4MD-"
```

This will produce four digits for the year and two each for the month and day.  The input will also be guided by it — it will certainly accept `2019-09-28`, but also looser variations such as `2018-9-28` or `2019/9/28` (the order matters most).  Unless you've set the `DBCENTURY` environment variable too, entering `19-9-28` will also produce the same result.

Comment: Muchas gracias, di con el comando a eso de las dos horas de la pregunta, olvidé publicarlo. De nuevo gracias.